# Return and List different values in different cells

Tags: worksheet-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RAR3.png)

I working on writing a formula that displays all users with status yes in different rows. Attached a small picture of sample data and how the result should look like. Please help

Comment: Use autofilter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following array formula (ctrl+shift+enter):
`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$9="Yes", ROW($A$2:$A$9)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$9))+1), ROWS($A$14:A14))),"")}`

Assuming the screenshot you posted starts from A1.
So you put this formula in A14 (ctrl+shift+enter !) and copy down as far as necessary (to be sure, in case status is "Yes" for all users, as far down as there are users).

Comment: Thanks Peter. This worked. With this I am moving to next step which is get results for multiple columns and the results should change based on the selection and I am having problem relating column names to dropdown selection. Here is the link for my question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657242/return-multiple-values-by-reading-multiple-columns-and-change-based-on-the-colum

Comment: @Puja You're welcome. If the formula works, please accept the answer so this question is flagged as closed and answered. I'll respond on the other question on SO.